# One one customer from table

Tags: sql, teradata

I need help using Teradata SQL and I hope you can help.
I have a table that looks like this:

```
email | article number | discount | price
customer01@test.de | 123 | 15 | 999
customer01@test.de | 456 | 30 | 1999
customer01@test.de | 789 | 30 | 999
```

From this table I want only row from the customer which has the highest discount and (if there are multiple rows with the same discount) the lowest price.

So in the example above, I only want the 3rd line. How can I write a SQL query for this?

Answer (score 2):

The most flexible way utilizes ROW_NUMBER:

```
select * from myTable
QUALIFY 
   ROW_NUMBER()
   OVER (PARTITION BY email -- for each customer, otherwise remove it
         ORDER BY discount DESC, price ASC) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is via a simple select statement ordered by discount (descending) and then by price (ascending).

```
SELECT * FROM customers
ORDER BY discount DESC, price ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row only if there are no other row with a higher discount, or another row with same discount and a lower price.

```
select *
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.discount > t1.discount
                     or (t2.discount = t1.discount and t2.price < t1.price))
```